# Rails: Make a repeating partial in groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, partial

Let's say I have a bunch of items and I want to iterate through them. I might have an `_item` partial to render these.

I could render these like so:

```
= render :partial=>'item', :collection => @items, :as => :item
```

For this example, let's say the partial is something really simple, like so (in haml):

```
.item= item.name
```

However, I'd like these items to be grouped in rows, so the markup ends up being like so:

```
<div class="item_row">
  <div class="item">Item Name</div>
  <div class="item">Item Name</div>
  <div class="item">Item Name</div>
  <div class="item">Item Name</div>
  <div class="item">Item Name</div>
</div>
<div class="item_row">
  <div class="item">Item Name</div>
  <div class="item">Item Name</div>
  <div class="item">Item Name</div>
  <div class="item">Item Name</div>
  <div class="item">Item Name</div>
</div>
<div class="item_row">
  <div class="item">Item Name</div>
  <div class="item">Item Name</div>
  <div class="item">Item Name</div>
  <div class="item">Item Name</div>
  <div class="item">Item Name</div>
</div>
```

I don't always know ahead of time how many items there will be / how many rows I need.

How could you create a partial, or wrap a partial, so it would render in groups like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use Enumerable's `each_slice` to group these 5 at a time and display them in a row:

```
<% @items.each_slice(5) do |items_for_row| %>
  <div class="item_row">
    <%= render :partial => "item", :collection => items_for_row, :as => :item %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```